# python datetime: strptime and strftime not converting same data correctly

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am converting a datetime object into a string to be passed over http to another server (in a json object as a field) where it is again converted to a datetime object using strptime. However, intermittently the two-step conversion does not result in the same data that was originally converted. Always, the error is reduction of one second in the final datetime object.

My python version on both servers is 2.7.6.

The sending server is running on django version 1.8.2. The receiving server is running on django version 1.9.

The date format I am using for conversion/de-conversion is "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ".

Conversion (on django 1.8.2 server):

```
in_time = datetime.datetime.now()
input_time_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(input_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

De-conversion (on the django 1.9 server):

```
input_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_time_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Is this supposed to happen or some version mismatch is causing this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `strptime` might discard the timezone information, that could be the problem. Try `python-dateutil`'s parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.now()` returns the time in your local time zone. When, subsequently, `strptime()` parses that time, it doesn't know which time zone it refers to; it probably assumes the system's default time zone, which might be different from the other system's.

You can use `datetime.utcnow()` instead to get the time in UTC.